# Infinite scroll in rails runs too many times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, infinite-scroll, stimulusjs

Trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zq_bEALI9TQ&ab_channel=GoRails) on creating a infinite scroll with stimulus in rails.
Here is what my view looks like :

```
<div data-controller="feed" data-action="scroll@window->feed#scroll" >
  <div data-feed-target="entries">
    <%= render(partial: "feed_posts")%>
  </div>
  <div data-feed-target="pagination"  hidden>
    <%== pagy_nav(@pagy)%>
  </div>
</div>
```

my rails controller:

```
  def feed 
    @new_post = Post.new
    @pagy, @posts = pagy(Post.where(user_id: current_user.all_following.pluck(:id)).or(Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)).order(created_at: :DESC), items: 5)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json{
        render json:{entries: render_to_string(partial: "feed_posts", formats: [:html]), pagination: view_context.pagy_nav(@pagy)}
      }
    end
  end
```

and finally my js controller:

```
export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["entries","pagination"]
    scroll(){
        let next_page = this.paginationTarget.querySelector("a[rel ='next']")
        if(next_page == null ){ return }
        let url = next_page.href
        var body = document.body,
            html = document.documentElement        
        var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight)
        if(window.pageYOffset >= height - window.innerHeight - 100){

            console.log("loading")
            this.loadMore(url)
        }
    }
    loadMore(url){
        Rails.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log(data)
                this.entriesTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.entries);
                this.paginationTarget.innerHTML = data.pagination
            } 
        })
    }
}`
```

The code in charge for finding out if the bottom of the page is hit runs different amounts of times each time and adds too many results to the view.

How can i make it run once hopefully or have it check to see if the html being added, was added before or not..or maybe that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique for this called `Throttle`: Guarantee the execution of the function regularly, only once every X milliseconds.

Check out details on [CSS-TRICKS - Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#throttle)

The simple way to use throttle with stimulus is using `_throttle` function from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle)

```js
_.throttle(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

Check out use case on [Debounce and throttle in Stimulus](https://fullstackheroes.com/stimulusjs/debounce-throttle/), [_.throttle inside a controller](https://discuss.hotwire.dev/t/throttle-inside-a-controller/100/2)

Answer (score 1):

The source for the tutorial you are using, GoRails, has a follow-up episode called [Throttling Infinite Scroll Events in Javascript](https://gorails.com/episodes/throttling-infinite-scroll?autoplay=1). If you are not a Pro member of that site, you will not be able to see the video, but there is a link to [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/infinite-scroll-stimulus-js/commit/3f18d53ef81a399e1bd2f641500145b32d1ffc91), which is freely available. It provides the following updated `infinite_scroll_container.js`:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["entries", "pagination"]

  scroll() {
    let next_page = this.paginationTarget.querySelector("a[rel='next']")
    if (next_page == null) { return }

    let url = next_page.href

    var body = document.body,
      html = document.documentElement

    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight)

    if (window.pageYOffset >= height - window.innerHeight) {
      this.loadMore(url)
    }
  }

  loadMore(url) {
    if (this.loading) { return }
    this.loading = true

    Rails.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        this.entriesTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.entries)
        this.paginationTarget.innerHTML = data.pagination
        this.loading = false
      }
    })
  }
}
```